# Saved markers not displaying on my map

Tags: javascript, php, xml, google-maps-api-3, markers

I cannot get my saved markers to display on my map.  My XML file is displaying correctly when opened in my browser (although I get a message at the top saying "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.")

Here is the code to my xml process file:

```
<?php 
require_once'db_connect.php';

function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
return $xmlStr; 
} 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM divesites_tbl WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'site_name="' . parseToXML($row['site_name']) . '" ';
  echo 'site_country="' . parseToXML($row['site_country']) . '" ';
  echo 'site_lat="' . $row['site_lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'site_lng="' . $row['site_lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'site_dive_type="' . $row['site_dive_type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';
?>
```

And the javascript & relevant HTML for my map page:

```
<script>
   //<![CDATA[
  var styles = [{
      stylers: [{
          hue: "#00ffe6"
      }, {
          saturation: -20
      }]
  }, {
      featureType: 'water',
      elementType: 'geometry.fill',
      stylers: [{
          color: '#010159'
      }]
  }, {
      featureType: "water",
      elementType: 'labels',
      stylers: [{
          color: '#ffffff'
      }, {
          strokeColor: '#000000'
      }]
  }, {
      featureType: "water",
      elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
      stylers: [{
          visibility: 'off'
      }]
  }, {
      featureType: 'landscape',
      elementType: 'all',
      stylers: [{
          color: '#0061a3'
      }]
  }, {
      featureType: "road",
      stylers: [{
          visibility: "off"
      }]
  }, {
      featureType: "poi",
      stylers: [{
          visibility: "off"
      }]
  }, {
      featureType: "transit",
      stylers: [{
          visibility: "off"
      }]
  }, {
      featureType: "administrative",
      stylers: [{
          visibility: "off"
      }]
  }, {
      featureType: "administrative",
      elementType: 'labels',
      stylers: [{
          visibility: "on"
      }, {
          color: "#c9c9c9"
      }]
  }, {
      featureType: "administrative",
      elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
      stylers: [{
          visibility: 'off'
      }]
  }];

  var map;
  var marker;
   //var infowindow;


  function initialize() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(31.267694, 17.341919);

      var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 3,
          center: latlng,
          minZoom: 3,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google_map_div'), mapOptions);
      map.setOptions({
          styles: styles
      });

  } //

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

   //var customIcons = {
   //Wreck Dive: {
   //icon: 'images/marker.png'
   //}
   //};

  function load() {

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("xml_output.php", function (data) {
          var xml = data.responseXML;
          var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

              var site_name = markers[i].getAttribute("site_name");
              var site_country = markers[i].getAttribute("site_country");
              var site_dive_type = markers[i].getAttribute("site_dive_type");

              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("site_lat")),
                  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("site_lng")));

              var html = "<b>" + site_name + "</b><br/>" + site_country;

              //var icon = customIcons[site_dive_type] || {};

              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  position: point
              });

              bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
          }

      });

  }


  function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
          infoWindow.setContent(html);
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
  }


  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
              request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
              callback(request, request.status);
          }
      };
      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
   //]]>
  </script>
  <body onload="load()">
```

Comment: Any javascript errors?  What is the value of markers.length?  Are the latitude and longitude values the ones you expect?

Comment: the map-variable is not global and the load()-function will not be called somewhere in this code.

Comment: Apologies, I call the load function in the HTML at <body onload="load()">   And the markers.length is dynamic and will be the amount of items in the array.  The map variable is not global?  Where do I need to place it to make it global?

Comment: Consider DrMolle's comment on your `map` variable.  Make sure it is in the same script as the rest of your code.  I don't see it in your code.

Comment: Thanks, please bare with me as I'm new to javascript.  so I placed the functions load(), bindInfoWindow() and downloadUrl inside the function initialize(), so now I just get the error load function is not defined, I guess I'm having trouble with the scope?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix my problem which was in the JavaScript scope / structure.  By placing everything inside the initialize function, and re-writing the code for getting the path to the image of the marker I fixed the issue

Below is my working code structure for getting markers from the database and displaying the XML output with PHP.  Note the onload="initialize()" is on the body tag of the HTML

The code that creates new markers is also here

```
var map;
          var marker;
          var infowindow;

          function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(31.267694, 17.341919);

            var mapOptions = {
              zoom: 3,
              center: latlng,
              minZoom:3,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google_map_div'), mapOptions);
            map.setOptions({styles: styles});


            google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng,
            map: map,
            });

            // click to create a new marker
            marker_position = marker.getPosition();
            marker_position_lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
            marker_position_lng = marker.getPosition().lng();

            var html = "this is the html to be placed in the infowindow";

            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
             content: html
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                  });
            }); //click to add site


            // display markers

            var InfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

            downloadUrl ("xml_output.php", function(data) {
                var xml = data.responseXML;
                var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    var site_name = markers[i] .getAttribute("site_name");
                    var site_country = markers[i] .getAttribute("site_country");
                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                        parseFloat(markers[i] .getAttribute("site_lat")),
                        parseFloat(markers[i] .getAttribute("site_lng")));
                    var html = "<b>" + site_name + "</b> </br/>" + site_country;
                    var markericon ='images/icon.png';
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: point,
                        icon: markericon
                    });
                bindInfoWindow(marker, map, InfoWindow, html);
                }
            });


            function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html){
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(html);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            }

            function downloadUrl (url, callback) {
                var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
                new ActiveXObject ('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
                new XMLHttpRequest;

                request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (request.readyState == 4) {
                        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                        callback(request, request.status);
                    }
                };

                request.open('GET', url, true);
                request.send(null);

            }

            function doNothing() {}

}
</script>
<body onload='initialize()'>
```